# Array formula with more than 255 characters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting an error when running my VBA code.

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class

I assume this is because I have more than 255 characters.

If this is the case, does anyone know of a workaround I can use?

My code is the beautiful mess below:

```
formula_string = "=-SUM("
account_counter = 1
Do Until Range("tblAccounts[[#Headers],[Accounts]]").Offset(account_counter, 0).Value = ""
    account_name = Range("tblAccounts[[#Headers],[Accounts]]").Offset(account_counter, 0).Value
    formula_string = formula_string & "IF(IFERROR(" & account_name & "[Category]=[@Categories],FALSE)*(" & account_name _
        & "[Transaction date]>=Budget!C$1)*(" & account_name & "[Transaction date]<=EOMONTH(Budget!C$1,0))," & account_name _
        & "[Outflow],0),"
    account_counter = account_counter + 1
Loop
formula_string = Left(formula_string, Len(formula_string) - 1) & ")"

    Do Until Range("tblBudget[[#Headers],[Ignore?]]").Offset(category_counter, 0).Value = ""
        If Range("tblBudget[[#Headers],[Ignore?]]").Offset(category_counter, 0).Value = "No" Then
            Do Until Range("tblBudget[[#Headers],[Ignore?]]").Offset(0, column_counter).Value = ""
                If Right(Range("tblBudget[[#Headers],[Ignore?]]").Offset(0, column_counter).Value, 8) = "Outflows" Then
                    Range("tblBudget[[#Headers],[Ignore?]]").Offset(category_counter, column_counter).Select
                    Selection.Formula = formula_string
                End If
                column_counter = column_counter + 1
            Loop
        End If
        category_counter = category_counter + 1
    Loop
```

If I replace ".FormulaArray" with ".Formula" and then manually make it an array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) it works fine so the formula itself works fine.

Unfortunately I can't make it much simpler as I could have as many as 10 accounts that each need to be referenced within each cell (the current three I'm using for testing has 525 characters but it'll change depending on whatever the name of each account is).

As I say, it seems Excel has no problem with this...it's VBA that has the issue.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you have some multiplications in your formula. You could split the formula into multiple named ranges and then use another range to combine them back. For example, lets say that your formula can be broken into two parts like this:

```
= formulaPart1 * formulaPart2
```

You can then define two named ranges via:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="firstPart" RefersToR1C1:="formulaPart1"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="secondPart" RefersToR1C1:="formulaPart2"
```

And then you can set your final result as:

```
= firstPart * secondPart
```

Edit: You could even define a named range for each of the elements you wish to sum. So for example this would be one named range to set, lets say you named it sumElement1:

```
"IF(IFERROR(" & account_name & "[Category]=[@Categories],FALSE)*(" & account_name _
        & "[Transaction date]>=Budget!C$1)*(" & account_name & "[Transaction date]<=EOMONTH(Budget!C$1,0))," & account_name _
        & "[Outflow],0)"
```

Then the formula would be something like "=-SUM(sumElement1, sumElement2,..., sumElementn)".

Answer (score 0):

I had several very long and complex formulas to insert.

I made a code that can insert long formulaarray-functions in english A1-notation (without "=" at the beginning)

Using the suggestion to substitute the formula, I am looking for the most common command "if()" to substitute the function dynamically in as many steps as possible. Maybe I can save you some hours of work by sharing.

The code wasn't intended to share, so it's poor at handling errors and the code is written trashy. If you need to improve it, do so.
The code is commented completedly in german and I am too lazy to translate it (since my english isn't that good). I will forget this post and may never check it again, so I can't answer any questions.

```
Public Sub InsertFormulaArray(formula As String, targetCell As Range)
'Die Zeile der Zellenangabe für die Platzhalter
'Existiert in der Formel eine Zeilenangabe, die diesen Wert enthält, muss dieser Wert geändert werden.
Dim uniqueLine As String
uniqueLine = 1337
'Substituiert If-Funktionen, die kürzer sind als dieser Wert
'dieser Wert muss kleiner sein als die R1C1-Notation jeder If-Funktion innerhalb der Gesamtfunktion.
Dim lenghtTolerance As Integer
lenghtTolerance = 150

'Initialisiert Array, um die Ersetzungen zu protokollieren
Dim arrLenght As Integer
arrLenght = -1
Dim replaceArr() As String

'speichert der InputString für die Prüfung am Ende
Dim InputFormula As String
InputFormula = "=" & formula


'Suche die IF Befehle
Dim currentIF As Integer
Dim replaceChar As Integer
replaceChar = Asc("A")
Dim compression As Integer

'Sprungmarke, für eine mehrdimensionale kompression
RestartReplacement:
'inputLen benötige ich für die Entscheidung, ob eine weitere kompression notwendig ist
'(vergleich vorher nachher)
Dim inputLen As Integer
inputLen = Len(formula)

'findet den Anfang der ersten If-Funktion der Formel
currentIF = InStr(1, formula, "IF(")
'Findet das Ende der aktuellen If-Funktion
While Not currentIF = 0
    'gibt die Tiefe der aktuellen If-Funktion an
    Dim depth As Integer
    depth = 0
    'gibt die position der letzten Ziffer der aktuellen If-Funktion an. (0 - nicht gefunden)
    Dim ifEnd As Integer
    ifEnd = 0

    'Setzt und initialisiert den Zähler
    '(Position im String bei der Suche nach dem Ende der Funktion)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = currentIF

    'Zu Debug-Zwecken habe ich mir die aktuelle Ziffer herausgezogen
    Dim currentChar As String
    'Schleife, bis das Ende der If-Funktion gefunden wurde - Fehler falls nicht
    While ifEnd = 0
        currentChar = Mid(formula, i, 1)
        'Ermittelt die aktuelle tiefe
        If currentChar = "(" Then
            depth = depth + 1
        End If
        If currentChar = ")" Then
            depth = depth - 1
            'Setze ifEnd, wenn genausoviele Klammern geschlossen wie geöffnet wurden
            If depth = 0 Then
                ifEnd = i
            End If
        End If
        'Zähler rauf
        i = i + 1
        'Gibt einen Fehler zurück, wenn "i" größer ist, als der String
        If i > Len(formula) And ifEnd = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Die eingegebene Formel ist keine gültige Englische Formel: " & """" & formula & """"
            End
        End If
    Wend

    'Gebe die ermittelte If-Funktion als String aus
    Dim ifFunction As String
    ifFunction = Mid(formula, currentIF, (ifEnd + 1 - (currentIF)))

    'Ersetze die IF-Formel, wenn sie kürzer ist, als lenghtTolerance
    If Len(ifFunction) < lenghtTolerance Then
        'Schreibt den String in ein Array
        arrLenght = arrLenght + 1
        ReDim Preserve replaceArr(arrLenght)
        replaceArr(arrLenght) = ifFunction

        'Substituiere die If-Funktion in die Formel
        formula = Replace(formula, ifFunction, Chr(replaceChar) & uniqueLine)
        replaceChar = replaceChar + 1

        'Wirft mich raus, wenn die Formel 26 mal substituiert wurde
        If replaceChar > Asc("Z") Then
            'Sorge dafür, dass ich beim nächsten Versuch aus dem While fliege
            currentIF = Len(formula) - 1
            'Sorge dafür, dass ich mich nicht mehr wiederhole -> compression = 0
            inputLen = Len(formula)
        End If
    End If

    'Sucht den Anfang der nächsten If-Funktion
    currentIF = InStr(currentIF + 1, formula, "IF(")
Wend
'Ermittel, wie stark die Funktion durch diesen Vorgang komprimiert wurde
compression = inputLen - Len(formula)

'Überprüft, ob noch IF-Funktionen vorhanden sind
'Wiederholt die kompression, falls die letzte kompression nicht erfolglos war
If currentIF = 0 And InStr(1, formula, "IF(") > 0 And compression > 0 Then
    GoTo RestartReplacement
End If

'Schreibt die komprimierte Formel in die gewünschte Zelle
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
targetCell.FormulaArray = ("=" & formula)

'Setzt replaceChar eins zurück, um den letzten ersetzenden Buchstaben anzugeben
replaceChar = replaceChar - 1

'Ersetzt rückwärts alle "replacements"
For i = arrLenght To 0 Step -1
    'Dim replacementStr As String
    'replacementStr = Chr(replaceChar) & uniqueLine
    targetCell.Replace What:=(Chr(replaceChar) & uniqueLine), replacement:=replaceArr(i), LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    replaceChar = replaceChar - 1
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Überprüfe das Ergebnis
Dim result As String
result = targetCell.FormulaArray
If result = InputFormula Then
    'Einsetzen erfolgreich!
Else
    MsgBox "Beim einsetzen einer Formel in die Zelle """ & targetCell.Address & """ ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!" & vbCrLf & "Die aktuelle Aktion wird abgebrochen!"
    End
End If
End Sub
```

You need to give a line never used in the code (to replace the if-command with a cell). This is needed because the inserted formula have to make sense for vba and excel in every step. The integrated FormulaArray and Replace-command will not work with senseless formulas wich is the main reason why I made this efford to substitute. In this case the uniqueLine is 1337, but you can change it if necessary.

The lenght tolerance is set to 150 that means only formulaparts shorter than 150 characters will be substituted. The limit of 255 counts for the formula in R1C1-notation even if it's given as A1-notation so the processed code is longer than the given formula and you need a bit headroom. You don't need that much headroom but it worked for me.

Have a nice day,

B_Nut